# Validation of second user input isn't working properly and I'm told I have a lot of unnecessary coding

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This is my first year in a Computer Programming course and one of my current assignments is to create a working Rock, Paper, Scissors game.

I have most of it working but my teacher has said that I have a lot of unnecessary code without actually telling me what it is.  I'd like to get this streamline as best as possible as I'm not just satisfied with whatever works.

As well, the second validation of user input (user makes a choice, program runs through and displays who wins then is asked to make a choice again) doesn't work like the first one and I can't figure out what's going wrong.  I've been looking at this for the past 2 weeks and can't figure it out so any help is appreciated.

The code that I have is as follows:

```
namespace Assignment04
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Declare variables
        int gamesPlayed = 0, userWins = 0, computerWins = 0, draws = 0, userSelection, computerSelection;
        bool inputIsValid = false;
        // Prompt user
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors game!");
        Console.WriteLine("1 - Rock");
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Paper");
        Console.WriteLine("3 - Scissors");
        Console.WriteLine("4 - Quit program and view record");
        // Create a loop to validate user's selection
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Please make a selection: ");
                // loop and test using TryParse()
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userSelection))
                {
                    // invalid data type
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
                    Console.Write("Please make a selection: ");
                }
                // test if input is within acceptable range
                if (userSelection >= 1 && userSelection <= 4)
                {
                    inputIsValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // valid integer, but out of acceptable range
                    Console.WriteLine("Number out of range.");
                }
            } while (!inputIsValid);
            // Display user's choice
            while (userSelection >= 1 && userSelection <= 3)
            {
                if (userSelection == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou have selected Rock");
                    gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed + 1;
                }
                else if (userSelection == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou have selected Paper");
                    gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed + 1;
                }
                else if (userSelection == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou have selected Scissors");
                    gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed + 1;
                }
                // Generate computer's choice
                Random randomNumber = new Random();
                computerSelection = randomNumber.Next(1, 4);
                // Display computer's choice
                if (computerSelection == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer has chosen Rock");
                }
                else if (computerSelection == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer has chosen Paper");
                }
                else if (computerSelection == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer has chosen Scissors");
                }
                // Calculate and display who wins
                if (userSelection == computerSelection)
                {
                    draws = draws + 1;
                }
                else if (userSelection == 1 && computerSelection == 3 || userSelection == 2 && computerSelection == 1 || userSelection == 3 && computerSelection == 2)
                {
                    userWins = userWins + 1;
                }
                else if (userSelection == 1 && computerSelection == 2 || userSelection == 2 && computerSelection == 3 || userSelection == 3 && computerSelection == 1)
                {
                    computerWins = computerWins + 1;
                }
                // Display results and statistics
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou have played {0} games with {1} wins, {2} draws, and {3} losses.", gamesPlayed, userWins, draws, computerWins);
                do
                {
                    Console.Write("Please make a selection: ");
                    // loop and test using TryParse()
                    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userSelection))
                    {
                        // invalid data type
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
                        Console.Write("Please make a selection: ");
                    }
                    // test if input is within acceptable range
                    if (userSelection >= 1 && userSelection <= 4)
                    {
                        inputIsValid = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // valid integer, but out of acceptable range
                        Console.WriteLine("Number out of range.");
                    }
                } while (!inputIsValid);
            }
            if (gamesPlayed == 0 && userSelection == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nGoodbye");
            }
            else if (gamesPlayed > 0 && userSelection == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nGames played = " + gamesPlayed);
                Console.WriteLine("User wins = " + userWins);
                Console.WriteLine("Computer wins = " + computerWins);
                Console.WriteLine("Draws = " + draws);
            }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with stuff like "C# & Visual Basic". Please use tags to indicate the categories that your question belongs in.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself writing almost the same thing multiple times, you should look for ways to refactor it. Here's an example of unnecessary repeated code:

```
if (userSelection == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nYou have selected Rock");
    gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed + 1;
}
else if (userSelection == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nYou have selected Paper");
    gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed + 1;
}
else if (userSelection == 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nYou have selected Scissors");
    gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed + 1;
}
```

Can be simplified to:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nYou have selected " + tools[userSelection - 1]);
gamesPlayed++;
```

Where tools is defined as:

```
string[] tools = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
```